# wordpress output numbers from an array of checkboxes

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I'm not a php expert at all, but I've just started to learn it. I'm using a function on wordpress which creates a xml file after pressing send button on a contact form (with contact form 7). That's my code for the moment:

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'CF7_pre_send' );

function CF7_pre_send($cf7) {
    $output = "";
    $output .= "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?>";
    $output .= "<cf>" . $_POST['codicefiscale'] . "</cf>";
    $output .= "<cognome>" . $_POST['cognome'] . "</cognome>";

    .......

    $output .= "<aree_tematiche>";
    $output .= "<area><macroarea>1</macroarea><subarea>" . implode(', ', $_POST['area1']) . </subarea></area>"; 

    $output .= "</aree_tematiche>";

   .......

   file_put_contents("wp-content/uploads/cf7outputtest.xml", $output);
}
```

Which is a really simple code. I'd like that if the user selects on the frontend a checkbox, his selection is displayed as a number and not with the entire string (as I'm doing now with the implode function). Furthermore if the user selects 2 checkboxes, I'd like that in the xml file the text is displayed as a loop like that, assuming that he has selected for instance checkbox 3 and 5:

```
<aree_tematiche>             begin of the loop

<area>                       first element of the loop, which shows checkbox n. 3
<macroarea></macroarea>
<subarea>3</subarea>         
</area>

<area>                       first element of the loop, which shows checkbox n. 5
<macroarea></macroarea>
<subarea>5</subarea>         
</area>

</aree_tematiche>            end of the loop
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is the actual structure of the data you are receiving in $_POST?

Comment: without implode function, so only with $_POST['area1'] I receive only "Array".
with implode function I get "text for checkbox", "text for checkbox", etc.

Comment: That’s what you get when you try to `echo` an array, or concatenate it into a string context. Use `var_dump` (or `var_export`, if you can’t see any live debug output in this context, and only write to a debug file or something), and figure out what it actually contains.

Comment: I've tested with var_dump but unfortunately nothing is shown.. maybe I didn't write the correct code. that's my code:

`add_action("wpcf7_before_send_mail", "wpcf7_do_something_else"); 

function wpcf7_do_something_else( &$WPCF7_ContactForm ) {
    $area1 = $WPCF7_ContactForm->posted_data['area1'];
    var_dump($area1);
}`

Comment: If this is using AJAX to submit the form data, then you need to check the response to that AJAX request (can be done in the network panel of your browser dev tools.)

Comment: I was able to print all the array in the end:

`Array
(
    [0] => a. AGRONOMIA
    [1] => b. PRODUZIONI ANIMALI
    [2] => c. ACQUACOLTURA
    [3] => d. AGROALIMENTARE
    [4] => e. BIOENERGIE
)`

so basically with $_POST['area1'] I gent "Array" and with implode($_POST['area1']) I get "a. AGRONOMIA" (if the first checkbox is selected). Basically now I only need to show "0" , so the index number.

Comment: Then use a `foreach` loop, with the extended syntax that gives you easy access to index and value.

Comment: Sorry but unfortunately I'm not such an expert and I can't write this piece of code. Googling somewhere I found the function array_keys which seems to work, but not properly for my use case:
`$output .= implode(array_keys($_POST['area1'])); 
   file_put_contents("wp-content/uploads/cf7outputtest.xml", $output);`

it seems like by selecting the checkboxes on the frontend, it creates an array on-the-fly in the backend. So if I select checkboxes 3 and 5, for instance, on my output file I get "0 1" and not "3 5".. I feel like I'm almost there :)

Comment: Only _checked_ checkboxes become part of the form data submission set - so unless these had specific names that already specified the index to use up-front, you will always get the checked ones in a zero-based array.

Comment: ok got it. As a workaround, if the checkbox number 5 is "5. Questionario" on the frontend, is possible to use string replace? So for instance on the backend "5. Questionario" is replaced by "5" and only this value is sent with file_put_contents? I've no other ideas :(

Comment: Just `explode` the value at the `.`, and take the first element of the resulting array.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't understand. If my code is that: 
`$output .= implode(array_keys($_POST['area1'])); 
file_put_contents("wp-content/uploads/cf7outputtest.xml", $output)`

how should I change it with explode?

Comment: You need to apply explode to the _value_ `5. Questionario`, to get the `5`. `foreach($_POST['area1'] as $subarea) { $temp = explode('.', $subarea); $number = $temp[0]; /*...*/ }` - and then in the `/*...*/` part, you need to create a new `area` and its children, and append it to your output.

Comment: got it :) I've understood now!